# Which is the correct way to configure IpAddress condition in Policy document for REST API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-policies, aws-rest-api

I'm trying to allow only specific IP addresses to access my API Gateway REST API without success.

I configured the following resource policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-west-1:my-account-id:rest-api-id/*/*/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws.SourceIp": "MY.IP.MY.IP/32"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I send a request using Postman I receive 403 forbidden.

If I set "aws.SourceIp": "0.0.0.0/0" I receive 403 as well.

If I remove the condition from the policy then it works (I don't receive 403), so I guess something is wrong with IpAdress condition.

I have a C# lambda function integrated with the REST API where I log the `SourceIp` to CloudWatch using the following code:

```
context.Logger.LogInformation($"SourceIp: {request.RequestContext.Identity.SourceIp}");
```

It logs the following:

> 2022-07-01T06:38:32.634Z  0dc80274-bbbb-494c-ba73-541f053ba5a2    info    SourceIp:
> MY.IP.MY.IP

What am I missing? How to properly write the policy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `"aws.SourceIp"` to `"aws:SourceIp"` and problem solved. Sorry for the typo.